# How to set value for has_many list in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth

I have the following form for a user model that has_many authorizations:

```
= @user.inspect
= @auth.inspect

= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|

  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} below."
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li.red-text= msg


  .field.ui-field-contain.ui-body
    = f.text_field :full_name, class: "ui-input-text primer corner all ui-shadow-inset", placeholder: "Full name"


  .field.ui-field-contain.ui-body.top-gap
    = f.text_field :email, class: "ui-input-text primer corner all ui-shadow-inset", placeholder: "email@example.com"

  .field.ui-field-contain.ui-body.top-gap
    = f.text_field :username, class: "ui-input-text primer corner all ui-shadow-inset", placeholder: "Username"

  .field.ui-field-contain.ui-body.top-gap
    = f.password_field :password, class: "ui-input-text primer corner all ui-shadow-inset", placeholder: "Password"

  = f.fields_for :authorizations do |a|
    = a.hidden_field :provider
    = a.hidden_field :uid
```

On the UsersController I'm setting the values of each param as following:

```
  def set_values_for_provider
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

    if params[:provider] == 'facebook'
      @user.full_name = auth_hash.info.name
      @user.email = auth_hash.info.email
      @user.username = auth_hash.info.nickname
    else
      if params[:provider] == 'twitter'
        @user.full_name = auth_hash.info.name
        @user.username = auth_hash.info.nickname
      else 
        if params[:provider] == 'linkedin'
          @user.full_name = auth_hash.info.name
          @user.email = auth_hash.info.email
        end
      end
    end


  @auth = @user.authorizations.build


  @auth.provider = auth_hash.provider
  @auth.uid = auth_hash.uid
end
```

And yet the value of hidden_attributes of Authorizations is not getting set or saved. In the HTML of the page, I'm getting the following output:

```
<input id="user_authorizations_provider" type="hidden" name="user[authorizations][provider]">
<input id="user_authorizations_uid" type="hidden" name="user[authorizations][uid]">
```

The value of hidden elements is NOT set, even though upon inspection the auth object shows both :provider and :uid values returned by OAuth gem. Any clues, where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE: Whitelist is as follows:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:full_name, :username, :email, :password, :cookie_token, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :designation, :location, :gender, :user_image,:bio, :dob, authorization_attributes: [:provider, :uid])
    end
```

Comment: Please post the `strong params` method of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Got the error I've made in strong params. The _nested_attributes_ should be white-listed in plural:

```
authorizations_attributes: [:provider, :uid]
```

instead of

```
authorization_attributes: [:provider, :uid]
```

Thanks @pavan for leading me to the spot. Thread closed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)